# tableau: creating bins for variable bound between 0 and 1

Tags: histogram, tableau-api, dummy-variable, bins

I have just started using Tableau and I have run into a problem. I want to create a histogram of the percentage of loans that have not been paid back. I created a variable called 'Delinquent num' coding the loans that have not been paid back as 1 and all others as 0. Then I calculated the percentage of loans that have been paid back (Delinquent pct) as (SUM([Delinquent num])/COUNT([Delinquent num]))*100.

I entered this variable on the sheet as the Rows variable and got

[image: Screen shot]

That is fine; about 18% of the loans go bad. But now I would like to make a histogram. That choice is not highlighted in the "show me" menu. I tried to create a 'bins' variable from the pull down menu from the variable itself but the option to create bins is not offered for the variable I created and I don't know why. Creating bins is offered as a choice for the Delinquent num but since everything is either a 0 or a 1 in that variable a histogram would not be terrible useful. Any suggestions?

Here is a link to the public notebook if that would be useful.

[Project3_working](https://public.tableau.com/views/project3_working/pctDelinquent?:embed=y&:display_count=yes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is Tableau does not allow to create a Dimension or a Bin based on a field that results in aggregated function.

An Option would be to use FIXED Level of Details on a specific Dimensions
[image: FIXED LOD by Home Ownership]

**Reference:**
 http://kb.tableau.com/articles/issue/unable-to-convert-measure-to-dimension?

Comment: Thank you very much. That explains it very well. I especially like the link to the explanation on Tableau's website. I had looked but had not been able to find it on my own.